# Fetching data using sequalise in which the date is lesser than that of now date

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, psql

Here is My Fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/20c29

I am trying to get the rows in which the date is lesser than that of the current date. My Node js code is as follows.

```
let nowDate = moment().startOf('day').subtract(7, 'days').toDate();
        console.log(nowDate);
        const campaign = await Campaigns.findAll({
            where: {
                campaign_end_date: {
                    $lt: nowDate
                  }
            },
            attributes: ['campaign_id',  'campaign_end_date'],
            required: true
        });
```

This is not returning any data how can I do that? I cant change the date type on psql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because the syntax `$lt` is deprecated and need a specific configuration to be used.

Here is the part of the doc that talk about this.

```
Deprecated: Operator Aliases
In Sequelize v4, it was possible to specify strings to refer to operators, instead of using Symbols. This is now deprecated and heavily discouraged, and will probably be removed in the next major version. If you really need it, you can pass the operatorAliases option in the Sequelize constructor.

For example:

const { Sequelize, Op } = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:', {
  operatorsAliases: {
    $gt: Op.gt
  }
});

// Now we can use `$gt` instead of `[Op.gt]` in where clauses:
Foo.findAll({
  where: {
    $gt: 6 // Works like using [Op.gt]
  }
});
```

So can you try using the new syntax.
Should be something like :

```
campaign_end_date: {
                    [Op.lt]: nowDate
                  }
```

Note that you need to import `Op` before.

And just for information the attribute `required` can't be use here.
It's just used while doing eager loading (inside an `include`) to turn an inner join into a left join (in a SQL point of view).

Here is the doc talking about it if you are interested :
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using v5 of Sequelize, you've to include Op because the key was moved into Symbol

```
const { Op } = require('sequelize')

const campaign = await Campaigns.findAll({
        where: {
            campaign_end_date: {
                [Op.lt]: nowDate
              }
        },
        attributes: ['campaign_id',  'campaign_end_date'],
        required: true
    });
```